# how to print dataframe values in pyqt5 in python

Tags: python, pandas, pyqt5

I have a python script that use pyqt5 in order to display in a TableView  the selcted dataframe.

I have 2 functions:

- first function load a csv file  it word .
- second function print the dataframe  into console it did not work.

the system display the below error :

> print(self.df) AttributeError: 'Widget' object has no attribute
> 'df'

## code:

```
from PandasModel import PandasModel


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent=None)
        
        vLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        hLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        
        self.pathLE = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        hLayout.addWidget(self.pathLE)
        
        self.loadBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Select File", self)
        hLayout.addWidget(self.loadBtn)
        vLayout.addLayout(hLayout)

        self.pandasTv = QtWidgets.QTableView(self)
        vLayout.addWidget(self.pandasTv)
        
        self.loadBtn.clicked.connect(self.loadFile)
        self.pandasTv.setSortingEnabled(True)

        self.dislayDF = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Display DF", self)
        hLayout.addWidget(self.dislayDF)
        vLayout.addLayout(hLayout)
        self.dislayDF.clicked.connect(self.print_df_values)



    def loadFile(self):
        fileName, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open File", "", "CSV Files (*.csv)");
        self.pathLE.setText(fileName)
        df = pd.read_csv(fileName)
        model = PandasModel(df)
        self.pandasTv.setModel(model)
        return df

    def print_df_values(self,df):
        print(self.df)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `self.dislayDF.clicked.connect(self.print_df_values)`you are directing a slot to a function with argument which is a dataframe but you are not passing any arguments to it. Since your class is extending QtWidgets and df is not any widget hence this error.
Try directing it to loadFile function.

Comment: i did not understand your comment.

Comment: You are calling print_df_values function when displayDF button is clicked. Just change it to loadFile function

Comment: i am using load file function in the select file button what i want is to print the dataframe into the concole  so it need different task

Comment: Try saving the df in a global variable like this 'self.df = df' in your loadfile function. then use this  self.dislayDF.clicked.connect(lambda: self.print_df_values(self.df))